# Return object implementing multiple traits - decorator pattern

Tags: rust, decorator, traits, decltype

I am currently implementing decorator pattern in Rust.
In Scala we could implement method chaining via traits like:

```
new Scanner
    with Whitespaces
    with Keywords
```

I want to do the same in Rust. So, different traits for scanner:

```
pub struct Lexer();

pub trait Scan {
    fn scan(&self, start: &String) -> DomainTags;
}

pub struct Keywords<T> {
    decorated: T
}
impl<T: Scan> Scan for Keywords<T> {
    fn scan(&self, start: &String) -> DomainTags {
        ...
    }
}

pub struct Whitespaces<T> {
    decorated: T
}
impl<T: Scan> Scan for Whitespaces<T> {
    fn scan(&self, start: &String) -> DomainTags {
        ...
    }
}
```

But since I want to build my lexers with method like:

```
pub fn build() -> ??? {
    let lex = Lexer();
    let lex = Keyword {
        decorated: Whitespaces {
            decorated: lex
        }
    };
    lex
}
```

I don't know if it is possible to statically deduce the return type to something like  `decltype(lex)`. What is the common approach, towards implementing the method? What could be improved?

**To clarify:** I want to return `decltype(lex)`, because I may also have multiple traits for single Lexer, like:

```
pub trait Load {
    fn load<T : Load>(&self, keywords: &String);
}

impl Load for Lexer {
    fn load<Lexer>(&self, keyword : &String) {
       ...
    }
}
```

And I hope to return a decorated object with implementation of Load trait as well. Both method load and scan should be available.

Comment: So depending on some condition, your function may return either a `Lexer` or a `Keyword` or a `Whitespace`? Then you need to return a `Box<Scan>`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've edited a question. In case of using multiple traits, should it be a Box<Scan+Load> or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can only return a single type of value, so the *type* returned by your function can't depend on runtime conditions. However that type may be a boxed trait, in which case the type of the value stored in the box may change provided it implements the appropriate trait (or traits).

From the example code you've provided, I think that `Lexer` should be a trait like `trait Lexer: Scan + Load {}` (or maybe the `Scan` and `Load` traits don't need to exist at all and the `scan` and `load` methods can be defined directly in `Lexer`). Then your `build` function should just return a boxed `Lexer`:

```
pub trait Lexer {
    fn scan (&self, start: &String) -> DomainTags;
    fn load (&self, keyword : &String);
}

pub struct Keywords<T> {
    decorated: T
}
impl<T: Lexer> Lexer for Keywords<T> {
    …
}

pub struct Whitespaces<T> {
    decorated: T
}
impl<T: Lexer> Lexer for Whitespaces<T> {
    …
}

pub fn build (cond: bool) -> Box<dyn Lexer> {
    if cond {
        Box::new (Whitespaces { … })
    } else {
        Box::new (Keywords { … })
    }
}
```